# How to make a squircle ImageView with Android

Tags: android, xml, imageview, shapes

Is it possible to make an ImageView into a squircle? i.e not just rounded corners but a [squircle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squircle)? If so, how do you do it?

Basically, I want a list of icons that are squircles, so doing it in XML and setting the background on widget would be ideal.

Comment: sure but not in xml, you need `BitmapShader` and `Canvas#drawPath()` method

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do it `in XML`. But you can draw them on a canvas object. But! According to the linked article, `A shape similar to a squircle, called a rounded square, may be generated by separating four quarters of a circle and connecting their loose ends with straight lines. Such a shape is very similar but not identical to the squircle.` They say "not identical". But, really, I can hardly tell the difference between the two shapes. And a squircle is much more computationally demanding.  Therefore, my counter-question is: do you really need a **squircle**? I'd go for a **rounded square**.

Comment: @Rotwang Yeah, I mean, that's just the normal way of rounding corners. They are super similar but I noticed that no one had ever asked this question before. Some manufacturers have them on their launchers so there must be a way to do it.

Comment: Yes, there is, as I said. It would not be very clever, since they are **so indistinguishable**, though. But yes, you can. **In Java**. And wasting machine cycles for a quite **useless** "feature". Who needs **expensive squircles**, when we can use **cheap rounded squares**?

Comment: That's why I asked for a way to do it in XML.

Comment: AFAIK, the answer is **NO**.

Comment: see http://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/details/KaJaWK/ and https://hackernoon.com/apples-icons-have-that-shape-for-a-very-good-reason-720d4e7c8a14, the first link helps in making it in bezier curves

Comment: @pskink Interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/MicroRJ/Android_Superellipse_Library

```
allprojects {
    repositories {          
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
dependencies {
            implementation 'com.github.MicroRJ:Android-Canvas-Squircle:1.0'
}

 <com.microdevrj.superellipse.custom_superellipse_views.SuperEllipseImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="64dp"
    app:colorFill="@color/colorFill"
    app:colorStroke="@color/colorStroke"
    app:paintStyle="fillAndStroke"
    app:strokeWidth="6dp" />
```

Feel free to look at the open-source files to learn how it works.

[image: A Squircle]

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: You're right in that. I will put up a detailed answer.